# SVN : How Subversion deals with committing multiple files at once?

Tags: svn, revision, subversive

How does SVN behave when committing multiple files at once : does it give the same revision number to each file, or give incremental revision numbers to each file ? what would be the next revision number of the repository ?

I'm using subversion 1.6 and Subversive Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Yes, all files have the same revision

Comment: say I have 20 as  head revision and then I commit 10 files, so the next head revision would be 30 or 22 ?

Comment: The next HEAD revision will be 21

Comment: by next I mean the revision number after a second commit,sorry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of-course we have to commit multiple files at once most of the time. Development of a feature or a bug fix consists of  changes in multiple files and they should be committed at once as a good practice with a clear message on what the change is about. It gives the same revision number to all. In the next commit revision num is incremented by one.

Answer (score 3):

Subversion uses consecutive numbers for versions. Each revision is an increment by one of the current latest version. Multiple file changes in one commit are still handled as one revision.

See [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html) for a reference from the Red Bean book:

> Revision Specifiers
>
> As we described in the section called “Revisions”, revision numbers in
>   Subversion are pretty straightforward—integers that keep getting
>   larger as you commit more changes to your versioned data.

You could imagine how easily you'll reach rather high numbers as revisions, if it were based on `current version + number of committed files`, if you had a project with a large number of files and a large number of active commiters and often refactorings which involve hundreds or thousands of files.

Comment: difficult for me to imagine that someone could hit the maximum commit numbers once (2^32 in 32 bits computers, a lot more in 64 bits ones)

Comment: @mounaim: Yeah, I know, I wanted to stress the fact that numbering like that would be a waste of numbers. Obviously, it would have to be a rather large project with tons of large-scale refactoring a large numbers of newly-created files every day... :D